# conv2d on non-rectangular image in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, convolution

I have dataset of images which are half black in a upper triangular fashion, i.e. all pixels below the main diagonal are black.

Is there a way in Tensorflow to give such an image to a conv2d layer and mask or limit the convolution to only the relevant pixels?

Comment: Suppose if it is a per pixel classification problem, in this case while calculating loss, you can  consider only indices of non black pixels in ground truth and prediction tensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the black translates to 0 then you don't need to do anything. The convolution will multiply the 0 by whatever weight it has so it's not going to contribute to the result. If it's not you can multiply the data with a binary mask to make them 0.

For all black pixels you will still get any bias term if you have any.
You could multiply the result with a binary mask to 0 out the areas you don't want populated. This way you can also decide to drop results that have too many black cells, like around the diagonal.

You can also write your own custom operation that does what you want. I would recommend against it because you only get a speedup of at most 2 (the other operations will lower it). You probably get more performance by running on a GPU.